# Strange behavior when overriding assignment operator on template class

Tags: c++, templates, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Below is an example of a template class which overloads the assignment operator. Given this class:

```
template<class Type>
class Attribute
{
public:

    Type operator=( const Type rhs )
    {
        mData = rhs;
        return mData;
    }

private:

    Type mData;
};
```

Why would this code below compile without any errors?

```
Attribute<std::string> str;
str = 0;
```

While seemingly contradictory, this code:

```
std::string test;
test = 0;
```

Produces the following error?

```
error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
```

Comment: First off, always overload assignment operator with a const reference, so this should read `Type operator=(const Type &rhs)`

Comment: @legends2k Not really. Pass by value allows you to employ copy and swap idiom for strong exception guarantee. Additionally it gives compiler more opportunities to elide unnecessary copies and will automatically invoke move constructor when available (C++11 only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has overloaded [operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator=), you code compiles fine but has undefined behavior when executing the string constructor because it doesn't accept NULL(thanks Potatoswatter)

```
basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s );
```

Note: `str = 0;` is equal to

```
std::string str = std::string(NULL);

std::string test;
test = 0;
```

Here, compiler can't deduct `0` is char type or pointer so it's ambiguous with below two operator overloads:

```
basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s );
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

*manually cast `0` to char or `char*` should make your code compile but you should avoid doing that.*

Comment: Then why doesn't this code compile? std::string test;
 test = 0;

Comment: @jlanisdev the difference is `std::string test; test = 0;` is calling assign operator not copy constructor.

Comment: @jlanisdev because that satisfies two different assignment operator overloads. You can assign from one character `s = 'x';` but you can't construct from a character `std::string s('x');` The compiler reports an ambiguous overload.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has [two assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator=)

```
basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s );
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch )
```

and 0 can match both the former and the latter. How? 0 is a valid char, [the null char](http://www.asciitable.com/), also it's valid to denote the pointer NULL value. Hence the compiler throws the `error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous`.

As for why is accepts it in your `Attribute` class case, the compiler is able to construct a std::string using [this constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

`basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

and passes it on as the `rhs` in your function `Type operator=( const Type rhs )`; this behaviour is because of [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) the compiler does.